# Different font for MKAnnotationView

Tags: iphone, google-maps, fonts, mkannotation

On the callout bubble on the iPhone SDK's map, can the font be changed for the title and subtitle properties.

I am displeased with the default font shown in the callout bubble, and would like to go with a different font face to match the rest of my application. However, I have not seen much mention of this, which has me concerned that it might not be possible.

I have seen the [Building Custom Map Annotation Callouts](http://blog.asolutions.com/2010/09/building-custom-map-annotation-callouts-part-1/) tutorial, and I guess that would work. But, if at all possible I was hoping that the ability to change a font was built into the `MKAnnotationView` much the same way I can change the font of a `UILabel` without subclassing it.

Comment: Pretty sure you're need to return a custom view, like in the tutorial you linked to. You might start by subclassing `MKAnnotationView`? http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKAnnotationView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use `MKAnnotationView`, or subclass it, to change the appearance of the title and subtitle labels as you suggest.  If you want to create more re-usable code, I'd subclass and add say properties to query and set the `UIFont` values to your `UILabel` instances.

Comment: Am I missing something? I don't see any UILabel properties available to configure on an `MKAnnotationView` object. Docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKAnnotationView_Class/Reference/Reference.html In my subclass's `initWithAnnotation` method I have `self.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"custom-map-marker"];`, that works great. I'd like to be able to set properties on a `title` and `subtitle` UILabel property as well... Please advise!

Comment: Also can't see how to change those properties in MKAnnotationView. Adding a custom callout view seems to be the only way.

Answer (score 2):

Subclass the MKAnnotationView then put the category below on top of its implementation:

```
@implementation UIFont (SytemFontOverride)

#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wobjc-protocol-method-implementation"

+ (UIFont *)boldSystemFontOfSize:(CGFloat)fontSize {

    return [UIFont fontWithName:@"Your-Font-Here" size:fontSize];
}

+ (UIFont *)systemFontOfSize:(CGFloat)fontSize {

    return [UIFont fontWithName:@"Your-Font-Here" size:fontSize];
}

#pragma clang diagnostic pop

@end
```

Comment: Subclassing the annotation view isn't necessary, this method will still work

Comment: Is it simple to do this in Swift?

Comment: Is this have no issues with Apple Approval Process?

Comment: But this still doesn't change the Font for iOS >= 8.0.