# How to change size of font in Map title iOS Xamarin (C#)

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm writing application for iOS (Xamarin C#)

I have map with some titles, but  it font size is too big. How I can make it smaller?

This is my code for Map:

```
MKMapView map = new MKMapView (UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);

        map.AddAnnotations (new MKPointAnnotation (){

            Title="МУРАКАМИ В ТРЦ «ОКЕАН ПЛАЗА»",
            Subtitle ="Пн - Пт 10.00 -00.00" +
                " Cб.- Вс 10.00 - 00.00",

            Coordinate = new CLLocationCoordinate2D (50.412300, 30.522756)
        });
```

And screenshot

[image]

Comment: You can try sub-classing MKPointAnnotation, have a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5328052/different-font-for-mkannotationview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Swift or C# things get more complicated than they should be (IMHO) as you can not override the system font in a `MKPointAnnotation` as you can not access the subview construction (or hierarchy) nor do some temporary ObjC magic on the system font calls.

- If someone does know how **please** tell me ;-)

I normally hide all this in a subclass'd MKMapView that uses completely custom drawn Annotation views instead of `MKPointAnnotation`, but this way is easiest to follow.

So I assign a custom delegate to the `GetViewForAnnotation` (a `MKMapViewDelegate`) property of the MKMapView before starting to add annotations.

### Example Setup/Call:

```
mapView.GetViewForAnnotation = myViewForAnnotation;
mapView.AddAnnotations (new MKPointAnnotation (){
    Title="МУРАКАМИ В ТРЦ «ОКЕАН ПЛАЗА»",
    Subtitle ="Пн - Пт 10.00 -00.00" +
    " Cб.- Вс 10.00 - 00.00",
    Coordinate = new CLLocationCoordinate2D (50.412300, 30.522756)
});
```

### Custom GetViewForAnnotation (a MKMapViewDelegate):

This is where you assign the custom font for any new `MKPointAnnotation` objects that need to be created but we are actually creating custom `MKAnnotationView`'s

```
public MyAnnotationView myViewForAnnotation(MKMapView mapView, IMKAnnotation id)
{
    if (id is MKPointAnnotation) {
        MyAnnotationView view = (MyAnnotationView)mapView.DequeueReusableAnnotation ("myCustomView");
        if (view == null) {
            view = new MyAnnotationView (id, "myCustomView", UIFont.FromName ("Chalkboard SE", 16f));
        } else {
            view.Annotation = id;
        }
        view.Selected = true;
        return view;
    }
    return null;
}
```

### Custom MyAnnotationView (MKAnnotationView subclass):

This stores the custom font that is passed via the constructor and handles the font assign on any `UILabel`s that exist in its subviews:

```
using System;
using MapKit;
using UIKit;

namespace mkmapview
{
    public class MyAnnotationView : MKAnnotationView // or MKPointAnnotation
    {
        UIFont _font;
        public MyAnnotationView (IMKAnnotation annotation, string reuseIdentifier, UIFont font) : base (annotation, reuseIdentifier)
        {
            _font = font;
            CanShowCallout = true;
            Image = UIImage.FromFile ("Images/MapPin.png");
        }

        void searchViewHierarchy (UIView currentView)
        {
            // short-circuit
            if (currentView.Subviews == null || currentView.Subviews.Length == 0) {
                return;
            }
            foreach (UIView subView in currentView.Subviews) {
                if (subView is UILabel) {
                    (subView as UILabel).Font = _font;
                } else {
                    searchViewHierarchy (subView);
                }
            }
        }

        public override void LayoutSubviews ()
        {
            if (!Selected)
                return;
            base.LayoutSubviews ();
            foreach (UIView view in Subviews) {
                Console.WriteLine (view);
                searchViewHierarchy (view);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

System Font / Default size:

[image]

System Font / 10 point:

[image]

Custom Font (Chalkboard) / 10 point):

[image]